# How to get specific rows in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried to call the database using ADO.NET and with the code I saw here last time...

```
private DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    public ActionResult ShowPage(int ID)
    {

        var query = from a in db.Products
                    where a.ID.Contains(ID)
                    select a;
        var item = query.FirstOrDefault();
        if (item != null)
            return View(item);
        else
            return View(db.Products.ToList());
    }
```

I got this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339357/how-to-get-a-specific-row-from-database-in-mvc-4) and changed some of it.

It shows the whole table in the database

---

I'm new to programming that's why I don't know how to use it.

I'm not sure but I think I use ASP.NET Web Application .NET Framework 4.7.x when I created it.

Comment: Your else condition says 
            return View(db.Products.ToList()); You are fetching all records in case you cannot find a particular ID in table.

Comment: How can I filter the result? Like I'm getting specific ID from database

Comment: db.Products.Where(record=>record.Id).ToList();

Comment: I got an error after I follow it, it shows [(CS1662)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1662?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1662)) [(CS0029)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0029))

Comment: Are you looking for pagination? Since I saw you have a page Id and your action result is show page.

Comment: I don't know what it called but I think that's it.


I plan to show every row in different div 


for example ID 1001 is in div1 and ID 1002 is in div2